# max dot size in R ggplot

Tags: r, scaling, ggmap

I am trying to write a R-Script that saves a series of Maps with Dots on it. For the Map I used `ggmap` and `geom_point` for the Dots. There is a map for each day in a certain time range.

The size of the Dots depends on a certain variable, but I have a problem scaling them. I am supposed to create later an animation of all the maps changing the dots' size through time, that means that I need a global scale for the dimension of the dots, spacing from the smallest value (zero) to the biggest value of that variable (the global maximum). In the most maps the biggest value is not reached.
I tried with:

```
scale_size_area(max_size = max(my_variable))
```

because `scale_size_area` allows to plot very tiny dots for the 0 values. I was hoping that the so written code would scale the dots correctly, using the global maximum as maximum size, but it doesn't seem to work. Every map has still a locally biggest dot that has the same size of any biggest dot in every map. Here's an example where two points with different values have the same size:

[image]

I hope I could explain my problem. I'd be glad to hear some suggestion.

Comment: I think that if you fix the same max for all the days, it can work. Means that if, for example, 4 is your max for all the days, just put 4 in your argument. I don't know if it will work however.

Comment: I think it's what i did, since the expression max(my_variable) has the same value in every map. For example "4". Still my dots are not scaled uniformally.

Comment: I just realized, that `max_size` doesn't refer to the value of the variable but just to the area of the dot, so I understand why it doesn't work, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You should probably use `limits` in this case.

Comment: `limits` worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To set the maximum and minimum values in a scale (size or otherwise), use `limits`:

```
scale_size_area(limits = c(NA, max(your_varible))
```

`NA` computes the minimum